# Tab icon wont disappear

Tags: html, css, tabs, icons

I'm using bootstrap basic theme and have been editing it, i deleted the code in html:  `<link rel="icon" href="img/icon.jpg">`

But the icon wont go away, I have saved and refresh but the icon is staying there. I've even deleted the image at where its located.

Comment: Clean your history/cache browser. Open and close your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to clear your browser cache and then refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the browsing history and the application cache. Can you try it on a different browser? If it does not follow in the new browser it should be a cache problem.

Comment: I have had this issue before. Can you share your <HEAD> tag code with us so we can help? Usually the favicon link is there.

Comment: Ok. Are their any included files in your webpage? Favicons can even be set dynamically by javascript. If you have access to your scripts, you can check for the phrase `favicon` to see if it is set that way. Without seeing the full code of your site, it is difficult to track down the reason the icon is not clearing.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: Opened it in a different browser and it was fine, my fault

Comment: Oh ok. Well glad you tracked it down.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if you also uploaded an icon to the root of the webserver under the name: `favicon.ico`. These icons also get loaded, independent on your html source.